# Gradient of integral of vector norm

Tags: normed-spaces, matrix-calculus

Since I'm beginner in matrix algebra, please help me to find the gradient of the following function with respect to $\phi$ and $u$, both are vectors. $ Bs, Bd\  and \ E$ are matrices

$$f(s,t) = \int_{-1} ^{1} \int_{-1}^{1}  {\left| [Bs][{\phi}]-[E][Bd][{u}] \right|}^2 ds\  dt\  det(J)$$

My try doesn't make any sense to me. I applied chain rule and got the following result.
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi} \ = \ 2*   {[Bs][{\phi}]-[E][Bd][{u}] } * [Bs]$$

Comment: Could you share what you've tried?

Comment: First, we must establish whether we can differentiate under the integral sign of the given function. Are you aware of the conditions under which we may do so? If yes, then does your function satisfy those conditions?

Comment: @SystematicDisintegration my function is differentiable and I have given my try here